# Why does filter always return an Array?

Tags: swift, swift1-2

I'm using swift 1.2.

When I invoke

```
let filtered = filter(mySet, <some condition>)
```

, I would think that `filtered` would have the same collection type as `mySet` but it is always an array.

I'm wondering what the logic is since a Set, for instance, doesn't have an order.

Comment: My guess is since `filter` existed as a global function long before sets were added to Swift, it didn't make sense at the time to make it return anything other than an array.

Comment: Yeah I guess filtering a range and returning a range wouldn't make much sense.